# Swing UI is damaged after call of SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI

Tags: java, swing, windows-10

We've faced a problem with Swing under Windows 10. Sometimes, when Windows 10 goes unlocked, our Swing application looks damaged. This problem comes sporadically for Windows 10 only. For Windows 7 we cannot reproduce this behavior. After some days of researches I've found the problem: Swing for some reasons calls the method `SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI`, which reset some of my UI hacks, that was required to provide better look for my components. My problems look like the problem described in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17345673/swingutilities-updatecomponenttreeuithis-removes-custom-document-from-jcombo), but I cannot use answer offered in the topic. The only one idea I have to fix this problem, is overriding of method `updateUI` in my "hacked" components to prevent reset of UI (so the UI can only be refreshed, when no UI was set before).

Have probably somebody better idea to solve this problem?

Comment: @Vulcan the problem is, that we have a legacy system with more than 150 man-years of development.

Comment: Please edit your question and show us these UI hacks which are affected by calls to updateComponentTreeUI.